# x86 assembly language homework prob

Tags: assembly, x86

I need help with a homework problem. I am supposed to figure out what the value of `edx` will be after this code runs.

```
0x40106e    <main+30>:      mov    $0x1,%edx
0x401073    <main+35>:      mov    $0x8,%ecx
0x401078    <main+40>:      test   %ecx,%ecx
0x40107a    <main+42>:      jg     0x40107e <main+46>
0x40107c    <main+44>:      jmp    0x40108a <main+58>
0x40107e    <main+46>:      lea    (%ecx,%ecx,1),%eax
0x401081    <main+49>:      lea    (%eax,%edx,1),%eax
0x401084    <main+52>:      lea    0xffffffff(%eax),%edx
0x401087    <main+55>:      dec    %ecx
0x401088    <main+56>:      jmp    0x401078 <main+40>
0x40108a    <main+58>:      // endpoint
```

Since it is homework I don't really want to know the answer as much as how to figure it out. I was having trouble with figuring out the loop, but I think I got it. I think the `test %ecx,%ecx` loops until `%ecx` is decremented to 0. Is that right? What's really getting me is all the `lea` stuff. I cannot figure out what that is doing.

Comment: The AT&T memory operand syntax is notorious. See here: http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html#Memory

Comment: Why not just single step it in a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the `test` and `jg`; it does indeed loop until `ecx` is zero.

## `lea`

I'm not very familiar with AT&T syntax, so I'll use Intel syntax (which I find more intuitive) instead. I hope it's still intelligible. (One of the main differences is that Intel syntax puts the destination first.)

Some instructions let you load a value from an address:

```
mov eax, [esi]  ; load a DWORD from the address in ESI
```

You can change these to add offsets:

```
mov eax, [esi + 4]  ; load a DWORD from four bytes after the address in ESI
```

Certain combinations of registers, scales, and offsets are allowed:

```
mov eax, [esi + ecx * 4 + 16]  ; load a DWORD from (ECX * 4 + 16) bytes after the
                               ; address in ESI
```

This is rather convenient; you don't need to calculate the effective address manually.

`lea` stands for “Load Effective Address”. Essentially, it lets you do something like this:

```
lea eax, [esi + ecx * 4 + 16]
```

Rather than loading the value in memory at that location, it just computes the address; in other words:

```
EAX = ESI + ECX * 4 + 16
```

The `lea` instruction above assembles to 4 bytes. In contrast, the most obvious way to me:

```
mov eax, ecx
shl eax, 2
add eax, esi
add eax, 16
```

…assembles to 14 bytes.

Comment: So what happens here:  lea    0xffffffff(%eax),%edx

Comment: @user2672982: In Intel syntax, that would be `lea edx, [eax + 0xFFFFFFFF]`. `0xFFFFFFFF` is negative one, so it's the same as `lea edx, [eax - 1]`. From that and my explanation above, you can show that it sets `EDX` to one less than `EAX`.

Comment: Oh I see my problem was I didn't remember that 0xFFFFFFFF was negative 1. I was thinking it was some giant number.

Answer (score 1):

As icktoofay explained, the `lea` instruction is going to set the `edx` register to `eax - 1`. Let's go through the whole code, step by step.

The first two lines are moving immediate values to registers, so `edx` is made equal to `1` and `ecx` is set to `8`.

The `test` instruction is at the start of the loop here and together with the instruction immediately after it states the condition for the execution of the loop. The `test` instruction affects quite a few flags, but as the conditional jump is `jg`, we'll only focus on `ZF`, `OF` and `SF`. `jg` branches only if `ZF=0` while `SF=OF`. Now

- `ZF` will be zero until `ECX!=0`
- `OF` will always be zero and the same applies for `SF`, as `8` is greater than zero in two's complement (more precisely the most significant bit of 8 is 0).

The first `lea` instruction sets `eax` to `2*ecx`. The second and the last `lea`s add `eax` to `edx` and decrement it. Finally, `ecx` is decremented and instruction pointer is set to the start of the loop.

Written out symbolically:

```
sum(8, n = 1, n*2 -1) + 1
```